# require difference in javascript(spidermonkey) and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

in  javascript(spidermonkey)

//t1.js

```
var a=function(){


};

a.prototype.dosomething=function(){
    console("t1");

}
```

t.js

```
require ('t1.js');
var b1=new a();
b1.dosomething();
```

it equals:

```
var a=function(){


};

a.prototype.dosomething=function(){
    console("t1");

}
var b1=new a();
b1.dosomething();
```

but in node.js

t.js

```
require ('./t1.js');
var b1=new a();
b1.dosomething();
```

it reports error:

node t.js

```
t.js: 
var b1=new a();
           ^
ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mymac/js/t.js:16:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS's module system does not leak globals (unless specifically asked to).

If you need to export a reference to it, you use `module.exports` as such:

```
//t.js
module.exports = a;

// requiring file
var A = require ('./t1.js');
var b1=new A();
b1.dosomething();
```

Keeping our global environment clean. In ES6 times, this will be done by module loaders.

See [this official documentation piece on modules to learn more](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

Comment: node t.js

t.js:16
var b1=new a();
           ^
ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: I have tested my code with `module.exports = function(){ this.doSomething = function(){}}` in t.js and this exact code in the requiring file and it worked and compiled.